# Is there a non-trivial countably transitive linear order?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory

A linear order $<$ on a set $S$ is countably transitive iff, whenever $A$ and $B$ are order-isomorphic countable subsets of $S,$ there is an order-automorphism of $S$ which maps $A$ onto $B.$ Does such an order exist on some infinite set?

#### Background

One book defined $n$-transitive for finite $n>0$ to mean that whenever $A$ and $B$ are $n$-element subsets, there is an order-automorphism that maps $A$ onto $B.$ It is easy to show that $2$-transitive implies $n$-transitive for all finite $n>2.$ I thought of extending this. I easily found an infinite $S$ ,with no largest member, where, whenever $A$ and $B$ are subsets of $S$, each order-isomorphic to $\omega$, there is an order-aut of $S$ that maps $A$ onto $B$ . Then I tried to extend it to this question. A solution must have the following properties : It is order-dense in itself, as no endpoints, has no $(\omega,\omega^*)$ gaps, and every countable subset is bounded and closed in the order topology.

Comment: Do the reals definitely not have this property?

Comment: @TheoBendit The reals definitely do not have this property. Consider $A$ as the rational numbers, and $B$ as the rational numbers in $[0,1]$. They are order-isomorphic, but any order-preserving function mapping $A$ onto $B$ must have image within $[0,1]$.

Comment: How about the [long line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_\(topology\)), in which every countable set is bounded?

Comment: Note that my former comment should use $(0,1)$ instead of $[0,1]$: to be order-isomorphic to the rationals, you can't have endpoints.

Comment: @ChrisCulter The long line is not an example.  Consider subsets of the form $L\cup R$ where $L$ is a strictly increasing sequence of points, and $R$ a strictly decreasing sequence, and every point in $L$ is less than any point in $R$.  All such subsets are order isomorphic, but in some the two parts $L$ and $R$ have two distinct limit points, and in some the limit points coincide.  I think possibly there is no simpler example than the ones in hot_queen's answer.

Comment: Assuming CH, two examples are: modest mouse, ultrapowers of rationals, $2^{<\omega_1}$. _(ed ajf)_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes. Every infinite structure has a strongly $\omega_1$-homogeneous elementary extension. So you can start with the rationals and find an $\omega_1$-homogeneous elementary extension $(L, <)$ which is countably transitive being $\omega_1$-homogeneous. You can find a construction [here](http://modeltheory.wikia.com/wiki/Saturated_model). If you also assume CH, then there is a saturated DLO without end points of size $\omega_1$ (which is clearly strongly $\omega_1$-homogeneous).

Comment: I don't know enough of that subject to follow it,but thanks for the answer.

Comment: If you read the contents of the link you'd see that this is really simple. I just didn't want to type much here.

Comment: @user254665  $\omega_1$ says this concerns countable substructures. "Homogeneity" says: substructures that look like each other, have identical relations to the whole. 

E.g. for linear order, if one strictly increasing sequence has a limit point, then all must.  

Notice we can embed any linear order $P$  in a discrete linear order, $P\times\mathbb{Z}$ with lexicographic order. No strictly increasing infinite sequence has a limit point in  $P\times \mathbb{Z}$, so $P\times \mathbb{Z}$ achieves one bit of $\omega_1$-homogeneity.  Full $\omega_1$-homogeneity is a much stronger demand.