# Are the hyper-reals countably transitive?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, model-theory

A hyper-real field is $ R^*=(R^N)_{/U}$ where $U$ is a free ultrafilter on $N$. 
If A and B are any countable order-isomorphic subsets of $R^*$, is there an order-automorphism of $R^*$ that maps $A$ onto $B$ ?

(This is a follow-up to my question [Is there a non-trivial countably transitive linear order?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381697/is-there-a-non-trivial-countably-transitive-linear-order))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is independent of ZFC. If the continuum hypothesis holds, the answer is yes, but it is also consistent that the answer is no.

To explain further, I'll have to use some model-theory terminology. If you're not familiar with it, you might want to take a look at [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturated_model) wikipedia page.

Countable transitivity is called "strong $\aleph_1$-homogeneity" in model theory. In general, a structure is strongly $\kappa$-homogeneous if any isomorphism between substructures of size $<\kappa$ extends to an automorphism.

Why does CH imply that $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/U$ is strongly $\aleph_1$-homogeneous? Well, any nonprincipal ultraproduct is $\aleph_1$-saturated, and if CH is true, then $|\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/U| = \aleph_1$ (this is because $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/U$ is a quotient of a set of size $\aleph_1^{\aleph_0} = 2^{\aleph_0} = \aleph_1$, and it can't be countable - $\mathbb{R}$ embeds in it). So $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}/U$ is an $\aleph_1$-saturated structure of size $\aleph_1$. In this case we just say it's saturated.

Now saturated models are strongly homogeneous. I.e. if a structure of size $\kappa$ is $\kappa$-saturated, then it's $\kappa$-strongly homogeneous. This is exactly what we want (with $\kappa = \aleph_1$). You can prove this easily by a back and forth argument: the saturation allows you to keep extending your automorphism by realizing types over what you have so far.

Comment: Just a minor remark, you can always show that the ultrapower construction of the hyperreals gives a model of size continuum just by counting equivalence classes.

Comment: The set of all functions from N to R has cardinal c. Equivalence classes on it can't be more than c, but the reals are isomorphically embedded so it can't be less than c

Comment: Yes, that's clear. But CH is necessary to make $\aleph_1$-saturated equal saturated for the hyper reals.